# Multi Armed Bandit and Price Optimization

Tags: optimization

I obtained a model fit:
Sales = 1020 -8.8*Price +2.1*online reputation

after substituting the value of online reputation, I came out with following demand equation: 1036.8-8.8*Price
Now to take out the revenue (sales*Price) I converted it to revenue function:
1036.8*Price - 8.8*Price^2

Now can I implement MAB for finding the price in order to maximize the revenue

Comment: Are you sure about using MAB in this particular case?

Comment: No I am not, is it a good idea. If not what shall I use. I m using R

Comment: This is the fifth time you have posted the same question.  Continuing to do so will likely cause the system to block you from asking any more questions.  It would therefore be in your interest to work on clarifying the questions you have posted.

Comment: This time the question is more specific as last time you asked me to keep the question specific

Comment: @whuber: my last question was on any optimization applicable. This question is specific on MAB implementations

Answer (score 1):

I completely don't understand why you're trying to use anything more complicated than find an vertex of the parabola described by simple quadratic equation.

In the general situation $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ the vertex point has coordinates:
$(-\frac{b}{2a}, -\frac{\Delta}{4a})$

In your case we're tring to find the vertex of the parabola described by
$$y = -8.8 \cdot x^2 + 1036.8 \cdot x$$

Your coefficients are $a=-8.8, b = 1036.8, c = 0$ and
$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = (1036.8)^2$

Maybe I don't see something, but at the first glance it's so simple.